# Maximum Message Size quota for Incoming messages has been exceeded exception

Tags: wcf

I increased the MaxReceivedMessageSize to 2147483647 but I still get this error. I put the same value on the server config and client config. Please helpppp

```
The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ThrowMaxReceivedMessageSizeExceeded()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.GetMessageBuffer()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ReadBufferedMessage(Stream inputStream)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ParseIncomingMessage(Exception& requestException)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at IService1.GetRecordsforMAR(Int32 showDeleted)
   at Service1Client.GetRecordsforMAR(Int32 showDeleted)

Inner Exception:
The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.
```

Comment: Since you're still getting the error with the lower limit, you're not changing the value in the right place: "...on the appropriate binding element."

Comment: I have changed the values on Client and Server config files. I am not sure where else i need to change it. I am new to WCF please help

Comment: If you want more help, you'll have to post the xml.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've set the values in the `<binding>` section of your config file, you need to make sure you reference those bindings in the bindingConfiguration attribute of the `<endpoint>` element:

I.e.,:

```
<bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MyWsHttpBinding" /> 
        <!-- Other values for this binding ommitted for purposes of demonstration -->
    </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<services>
    <service name=MyService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyWsHttpBinding" contract="IMyContract" />
    <service>
</services>
```

Obviously this is not a complete config file, it's merely a visual demonstration of the relationship between the `<endpoint>` bindingConfiguration attribute and the `<binding>` name attribute.  If you don't set this, WCF will give you a binding with the default values.

Comment: Thanks for that, just want to add that those changes should be applied on both server and client to make it work (those settings are  maxBufferPoolSize and maxReceivedMessageSize.)